# Adding Age Based Wordpress Category

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I want to create a WordPress blog that shows public profile. I have added a category for that "Age" because i want to show the list of all the people who have same "Age". Now the problem is with age. 
I don't want to update every individual's age again and again. A person's age will change as per their DOB.

How to create the age-based custom taxonomy that changes automatically for an individual post?

Comment: You don't need custom taxonomy for this, instead create a custom field for `DOB` (if you don't have that already) and then check `DOB` in a custom `WP_Query` with the help of `meta_query`.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I am not a developer, just a blogger who wants to improve visitors experience. 
I want to store all the "DOB" of people in DB so that i can make more pages that ommit the data.
I have downloaded "Advance custom field" plugin but don't know how to use it. I need help from the strach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to:

- Use a [custom field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) as @[Fayaz](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/110572/fayaz) mentions above. [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) will be the best for this (and you have it already).
- Add a new field (and I'd call it 'Year of birth') using [Range](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/range/). You could use a datepicker, but this way it's cleaner and less intrusive:

[image: Year of birth]

- This will then give you nice stable meta data for each post ('stable' as in their 'year of birth' doesn't change; age does!).
- You can then 'call' that meta data depending on what you want.
- If you wish to reference posts that are of a certain age range, you can do this with a WP_query using meta_query.
- If you want to show someone's age on a post, you could use **[current_year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003/how-do-i-use-php-to-get-the-current-year)** minus **Year-of-birth**.

Note that this requires some level of development. This is [Wordpress development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) after all..!